# Cartoon about 3, maybe 4 kids that use a portal to travel to another world and fight evil with these weird animals

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, parallel-universe, animation

I remember watching a show during my childhood, maybe when I was 12-13. There were 3-4 kids who were the main characters. I think the main boys name was hiro/hero. He found a portal or some sort of weird teleporty thing that brought him to a different world, where he met this weird tiger like creature, that could be summoned through a disk, or maybe a device of some sort. Does anyone know what cartoon I’m thinking of?

Update: I FOUND IT it’s called invizimals. YouTube is a godsend. I’m so happy lol

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and was the animation traditional 2D or 3D/CGI? Also, can you describe the 3-4 kids a bit more, like their sex and hair colour, and were there any villains that you can recall?

Comment: @LogicDictates I believe it was a mix between 2D and CGI. Two of the kids were male and one was female. The main kid, I think he had short brown hair, peach, but maybe slightly tan skin, green or blue eyes, and he wore goggles. I don’t remember what the other boy looked like. I think the girl had pink dyed hair? I don’t quite remember. I don’t remember any of the villains. I believe I watched this around 2015-2016

Comment: Please post this as an answer instead of editing it into your question.